# TFS does not allow the NuGet packages to be installed/Updated

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am in VS2015/TFS environment and I have been having this constant issue with TFS Source Control:

- Every time I want to install the package, it fails with following error

> Install failed. Rolling back... Package 'jQuery.Cookie 1.4.1' does not
>   exist in project 'Web'

- This is the same exact error that I see every time I try to install any of the packages.
- Currently, I have been taking a copy of my project folder and then put it somewhere where I do not have any SourceControl, then I install the package and copy it back to its original location

  - The only problem with this approach is that it is a lot of tedious work everytime I want to install a new package
  - Also, all the packages installed in this manner are not recognized by the source Control and that is why I have to add each file saperately. Not to mention that since it is not as accurate as having Nuget taking care of everything for me, sometimes I miss to check in some of the files and it breaks things on the server.

Can someone guide me on how can I smoothly install an new NuGet package on VS 2015 without having to go through this tedious process?

Comment: Are you updating via the Nuget Package Manager Console or via the UI?

Comment: What do you mean that your packages are not recognized by source control?

Comment: Which nuget version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the bug in old nuget version: [Install package fails when solution/project is bound to TFS source control](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1164)

Update nuget to latest version and then try again.